# LWJGL glDrawElements(int, int, int, long) Draws Nothing, While glDrawElements(int, IntBuffer) Draws Properly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I started playing around with OpenGL 3.3+ last week, and I ran into this problem when trying to get indexed drawing to work. Right now, I'm just trying to get a triangle to draw using an IBO.

Index buffer, and `indexHandle`:

```
int[] tIndices = {
    0, 1, 2
};

IntBuffer indexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(tIndices.length);
indexBuffer.put(tIndices);
indexBuffer.flip();

int indexHandle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexHandle);
glBufferData(indexHandle, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

This is the main drawing loop in my program, which draws nothing:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programHandle);

    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexHandle);

    // This call does nothing v
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, tIndices.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glUseProgram(0);
    Display.update();
}
```

This is the main loop with the `glDrawElements(int, IntBuffer)` variant (which does draw my triangle):

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programHandle);

    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // indexBuffer is an IntBuffer
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glUseProgram(0);
    Display.update();
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the 1st block is not drawing anything at all? What am I doing wrong?

Also, the 2nd block runs at about 1.3k FPS on a 600x600 window, while the 1st one is about 800 FPS. Why is this?

I will provide more information in the morning if anyone needs them

Comment: Interesting... I'll try to replicate this behavior...

Comment: Also post the code where you create the GL index buffer (ie initialize indexHandle) and upload the data to the buffer.

Comment: Ok, I added that part of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument to `glBufferData()` is wrong for the index buffer. You have this:

```
glBufferData(indexHandle, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The first argument is the target, not the buffer id. It should look like this instead:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```